# Heavy optimization issues Android Java

Tags: java, android

I know this surely is too generic of a question, but I have incredible lag and "frame skipping" in the app I developed, it's nearly unusable. I'm not asking you to go through the whole code, but maybe taking a quick look could "turn on a light" on the more experienced programmers, like "ooh that's why, optimize here"

Thank you! And if the question is too generic and illegal, I'll delete it

EDIT: Thank to Dean Wild I found out where the error is, but I didn't get how I can fix it

```
           LoginIstance.getIst().setLog(user.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString());
            HttpLogin connection = new HttpLogin(LoginIstance.getIst().getLog()[0],LoginIstance.getIst().getLog()[1]);

            connection.execute();
            while(connection.finish()){
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                }
            }
            match = connection.getStringa();
```

Looks like this is the part that is messing up my app. I need the connection AsyncTask to be over before doing other things, but as the guy said, it freezes my UI thread. How can I achieve that without using thread.sleep?

Comment: Use Traceview to determine where your problems lie.

Comment: Offering this link to the Android Performance Patterns videos if you haven't seen them: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc9CBxr3BVjPTPoDPLdPIFCE

Comment: Don't link to external code. Post the relevant bits directly here instead.

Answer (score 0):

At a glance of your [MainActivity](https://github.com/leejaku/RemoteAndroid2/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/lee/remote_android/MainActivity.java) I see the following code

```
                LoginIstance.getIst().setLog(user.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString());
                HttpLogin connection = new HttpLogin(LoginIstance.getIst().getLog()[0],LoginIstance.getIst().getLog()[1]);

                connection.execute();
                while(connection.finish()){
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                    }
                }
                match = connection.getStringa();
```

You appear to be executing a network call with `connection.execute()` which I presume is Asynchronous (which is a good thing). But then you are running a while loop with a Thread.sleep until the network operation is complete. This code is running on the UI thread and these Thread.sleep calls will cause your UI to completely lock up.

You seem to lack a fundamental understanding of the UI thread in Android and therefore I suspect you are making these mistakes all over your codebase.

Try reading up on [this](http://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html)

For the record, this particular problem could be solved by passing connection.execute some sort of interface callback which executes after the operation is complete.

Example:

```
// create a callback interface
interface NetworkCallback {
    void onNetworkCallFinished();
}

// pass in your interface to the network call
HttpLogin connection = new HttpLogin("...", "...", new NetworkCallback(){
    void onNetworkCallFinished(){
        // now your data will be there
        match = connection.getStringa();
    }
});

connection.execute

// change your HttpLogin to take a reference to this callback
public HttpLogin(String s1,String s2, NetworkCallback callback){
    usr=s1;
    pss=s2;
    this.callback = callback;
}

// in your network call, override onPostExecute and notify the callback
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    callback.onNetworkCallFinished();
}
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer :) Yes, I've been making this mistake all over the code, but I'm not sure what you mean. What shall I pass to the Asynchronous network operation?

Comment: I can't access connection itself inside the method onNetworkCallFinished